# custom context processor not working for displaying cart items

Tags: django

This is my custom context code for displaying cart

```
def cart(request):
    return {'cart': Cart(request)}
```

and added this line to the context_processors in settings

```
'appname.context_processor.cart',
```

but not getting out put on base.html templates

template code

```
{% with total_items=cart|length %}
{% if cart|length > 0 %}
  Your cart:
  <a href="{% url 'cart_detail' %}">
    {{ total_items }} item{{ total_items|pluralize }},
    ${{ cart.get_total_price }}
  </a>
{% else %}
  Your cart is empty.
{% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Did you see any errors when you load your page?

Comment: How do you render the template in your view?

Comment: @kyore no errors, not getting any output

Comment: @bmons Misunderstanding =) i was interested in the part of your view where you call `render(....)`. But looking at your template, are you sure whatever `Cart` is has a length?

Comment: @schwobaseggl yes, I tried it on other templates and it gives me result

Comment: @schwobaseggl in single template it works, but I want to show it on base.html